# How can I position an imageView and a label in a stackView in a way that enables me to resize them according to their state?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I am coding a quiz app. The questions are shown in a tableView where there are 2 kind of cells.QuestionCell and MultipleChoiceCell.For each question I have a QuestionCell and 4 MultipleChoiceCells.

The problem:

This is how multipleChoiceCells should look like if the cells consist of text.

[image: Text Question]

and this is how they should look like if they consist of photos.

[image: Photo Question]

this is a multipleChoiceCell

[image: multipleChoiceCell]

Even if the choices consist of photos at the very least the label which is next to the imageView will show "A) or "B)" or "C)" or "D)" for every question. Also the imageView's width and height is 150.

And if the multipleChoiceCell consists of text and no image for that question then it should use all the width of the stackView.

I have tried many different approaches with or without using stackViews in the last 8 hours but could not find a solution. The closest I ever come to a solution was without using a stackView but it failed on the iPhone 5s screen size. The screenshots I have shown above were from that solution on my iPhone X.

How do I solve this? Please shed me some light...

Edit:When stack view is used the below problem occurs.MultipleChoiceCell has images but I still need the label to show "A" "B" "C" or "D".Also the label takes too much space no matter what I do.

[image: Problem with StackView]

Comment: Your question is not clear... *"it failed on the iPhone 5s screen size"* ... How did it fail? Maybe add a screen-cap of how it looks on the 5s?

Comment: On 5s the label could not be seen at all. I will try to revert back and take a screenshot. It will take some time though...

Comment: For the stack view solution, if you hide the image view when it's not required, does the text label not occupy the full width?

Comment: @DavidSteppenbeckPhD With stackViews the problem is the exact opposite.The label takes too much space. I edited the question with a screenshot.

Comment: What I meant is that in cases where you *only* have text but no image, then the text should fill the whole width of the cell, right?

Comment: @DavidSteppenbeckPhD Yes,that's right.

Comment: So, based on your new screenshot, I guess you want the image to appear as close to the label as possible, rather than on the far right hand side?

Comment: @DavidSteppenbeckPhD That's what I am trying to do. For example "A) [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using `UIStackView` is the way to go. You just have to make sure certain constraints and hugging priorities are set properly to get your desired look. If I've understood you correctly, I think this is what you are want:

[image]
[image]

I embedded the `label` and `imageView` in a horizontal `stackView` with properties:

```
stackView.alignment = .fill
stackView.distribution = .fill
imageView.contentMode = .left
```

Also, `imageView` has a fixed height constraint of 150, but no width constraint.
The `label` has a horizontal hugging priority of 751.

(i) In the case where you want text in the `label` to fill the whole width (but no image), do this:

```
imageView.isHidden = true
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

(ii) In the case where you want short text, such as A) etc, and an image, do this:

```
imageView.isHidden = false
label.numberOfLines = 1
```

Comment: In fact, you could even set the label hugging priority to required (1000) and then you could probably just keep label.numberOfLines = 0. Play around and see!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I spent my all day trying to figure that one out. I am now trying to solve another small problem. After doing this, the tableviewCell height is always 150 because of the imageView height. Since automaticDimension is on, I need it to be 60 when there is no image so that the cell size is not too small for short text(the clickable area), and 150 when there is an image. So I am playing around with the imageView height constraint. I set it to greater >= 60 but since the original image sizes are a lot bigger this became a problem. Right now I am trying to figure that out.

Comment: Just put the height constraint on the stackView instead of the imageView and update its constraint.constant value, depending on the situation.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much.